# Upload dag in an activated form

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

When I upload a dag to the airflow and I see it in the airflow console I always see that it is uploaded as deactivated, and I must activate it manually, is there a way to upload the dag in an activated way?

Does anyone know how to do so that when I upload my dag it already has the activated status?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an option use:

```
DAG(dag_id='your-dag', is_paused_upon_creation=False)
```

[For more details see the original docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html#airflow.models.dag.DAG).

You can also set it in your airflow cfg file.